# Unable to delete fresh AWS Directory Service instance (MS Active Directory)

Tags: aws-directory-service

I created an AWS-hosted MS Active Directory instance for testing but never actually used it. I've been trying, repeatedly, to delete it but been blocked since "it still has authorized applications".

Only problem is I never did anything with this directory service. Two items, Amazon WorkDocs and WorkMail, do have a URL to application url but there's nothing there when I go to that address. The only option seems to be enabling everything in order to turn it off again but I'm sure it will use this Directory Service for authentication. Yeah, and if I had found an easy way to manage those entries from my Linux world I wouldn't be trying to shut down this service now. Chicken, meet egg.

I can't be the only person who has ever brought up this service and decided it was unneeded. Does anyone have any ideas short of closing this AWS account? Not joking - this was for a personal side project and it will be annoying but better than paying $84/month for nothing.